# unable to change the text color of sphinx_rtd_theme sidebar

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx, textcolor

I'm trying to customize the docs created using sphinx_rtd_theme. The default theme has a sidebar of background colour black and text colour white. I've successfully changed the background colour of the sidebar to white from black using

```
/* Sidebar header (and top-bar for mobile) */
.wy-side-nav-search, .wy-nav-top {
    background: #fafafa;
}

/* Sidebar */
.wy-nav-side {
    background: #fafafa;
}
```

but unable to find the right class or element for changing the text colour of the sidebar to black from white so that it's visible on the white background which I've done.

Comment: Can you provide more of your html so we can see what is that text under. If its a link or a button or just simply inside a div.

Comment: I think you are missing something, there's no HTML here we are talking about the sphinx documentation generator tool which builds the HTML from rst and I'm trying to add custom CSS in the documentation by adding `def setup(app): app.add_css_file('theme.css')' in the conf.py and I've already shared the css in the question asked.

Comment: did you inspect your site you should be able to see it using inspector what specifically part of the theme, the text is under. Seeing that will provide you more specification which one you want to call on the css.

Comment: Inspecting the site, getting the css attributes and overriding from the custom.css file helped me change the text colour. Thank you @Crystal. This was the class I was needing `.wy-menu-vertical a { color: #2f2f2f; }`

Comment: No worries glad it helped you. I'll write the answer so we can close this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change a specific class and having a hard time finding which css attributes you need to change, by inspecting your website using inspector on your browser will help you identify which class/id specifically you need.

Right click on the area you want to see then click inspect then you will be able to see all the elements that the page is using.